# Read from json data child and insert as <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this simple json:

```
{
    "music": {
        "albums": {
            "foobar": {
                "track": [
                    {"name":"foo","ref":"1"},
                    {"name":"bar","ref":"2"}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I wish to get the data from `foobar` and insert it into a unordered list **dynamically** like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

I am pretty new to json, I get the basics of it though, how would I go on about doing this?

I'd use the jquery `$.getJSON` but I am unsure what to do from that point.

Comment: Is that the exact JSON you are using? Doesn't look right. For example, I would expect the `foobar` object to contain an array of tracks. Right now, `foobar` is an object with two properties, both called `track`, so the parser will just ignore the first `track`.

Comment: are you creating that structure? `foobar` should be array

Comment: You have not proper json output. there should be array of foobar

Comment: Fixed the syntax, there is now an array instead of two properties both called 'track'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to fix our JSON. Instead of using Tack we will use 'Tracks' and make it an array of object. 
So here is the updated JSON.

```
{
"music": {
    "albums": {
        "foobar": {
            "tracks": [
                {
                    "name": "bar1",
                    "ref": "1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "bar2",
                    "ref": "2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "bar3",
                    "ref": "3"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

You can either use $.each or a for loop to iterate through the array and construct lis.
HTML : We have a ul with ID 'some-ul'. We need an ID so that we can add the lis once we get our track names.

jQuery :

```
var templi = '';
$.each(jsonData.music.albums.foobar.tracks, function(index, value){//loop through track array
  //construct lis here
  templi += '<li>'+value.name+'</li>';//since we just need the track name we use value.name
});
$('#some-ul').html(templi);//in the end add the lis to our ul
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsouzaalfred/xxvgekzf/2/) 
[jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) 
[Use this to validate your JSON](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: This is a great answer, however this does not seem to work with my code, it logs " Cannot read property 'albums' of undefined" with this code:

`var json = $.getJSON("/js/content.json");
var templi = '';
$.each(json.music.albums.foobar.tracks, function (index, value) {
    templi += '<li>' + value.name + '</li>';
});
$('#new-releases').html(templi);`

Comment: I fiddled a little with the code, and now it works! Thank you. I changed it to: `var json = $.getJSON("/js/content.json", jsonDo);

function jsonDo(data) {
    var templi = '';
    $.each(data.music.albums, function (index, value) {
        if (typeof data.music.albums !== 'undefined') {
            createAlbumSection(value.albums);
        }
    });
    $('#new-releases').html(templi);
}`

Comment: Only issue is now, it returns undefined on `value.albums`, which is weird cause it didn't for the tracks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you should correct your JSON structure for example `foobar`should be an array instead of an object:

Then you just need to loop through this array and create elements using iterated `track` object's values:

```js
var str = '{"music": {"albums": {"foobar": [{"track": {"name": "foo","ref": "1"}},{"track": {"name": "bar","ref": "2"}}]}}}';

var json = JSON.parse(str);
console.dir(json);
var array = json.music.albums.foobar;
console.dir(array);
var myUL = document.getElementById("myUL");
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.value = array[i].track.ref;
  li.innerText = array[i].track.name;
  myUL.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

**Note:**

I edited the structure of your JSON, to use `foobar` as an `array` and each `track` as an `object`.

Comment: The json is a separate file, and I am using jquery's `$.getJSON` to get the data.

Comment: In that case you have to edit your JSO file and then you can proceed like in my answer.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it and accept the answer if it works. Thank you :)

Comment: It worked, but I used the above solution as it used less code and was easier for me to understand. Thank you anyway, you've been very helpful.